# Set the size of an array in one class from the main class in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row=in.nextInt();
        int column=in.nextInt();
        Matrix a=new Matrix(row,column);
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
                a.entry[i][j]=in.nextFloat();
    }
}
class Matrix{
    int row,column;
    Matrix(int a,int b){
        row=a;
        column=b;
    }
    float[][] entry=new float[row][column];
}
```

I tried to set the size of the 2d-array `entry`, but it's always set to zero.

It gave me a run-time error - array index out of bounds at line 13:

```
a.entry[i][j]=in.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you're directly doing:

```
float[][] entry=new float[row][column];
```

inside the `Matrix` class, its `row` and `column` variables were initialized as `0` earlier. It doesn't matter that the definition of `entry` is placed after the constructor, because all field definitions are executed before the constructor.

We need to pass user's `row` and `column` to the `Matrix` class.

Initialize `entry` inside the constructor of `Matrix` class like:

```
class Matrix{
    int row,column;
    float[][] entry;
    Matrix(int a,int b){
        row=a;
        column=b;
        entry=new float[row][column];
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but please some more explanation

Comment: Nice. I added one more sentence about the order of initialization, I hope you agree.